# largest monotonically increasing or decreasing subsequence

Tags: python, algorithm, subsequence

The below is my code for largest monotonic subsequence (either increasing or decreasing).  I hadn't done any research prior to coding this up and was unaware that it is a common computer science question.  From my subsequent research, it seems that the generally accepted most efficient algorithm is O(N log N).  These are typically dynamic programming type solutions which are a bit over my head at this time.

I'm not an algorithms expert, but isn't the following code O(N)?  I pass through each list twice, once to find increasing sequence, once for decreasing.

I would also appreciate any advice at cleaning it up.. i realize the functions are very duplicative but I couldn't find a nice way to do it all in one go without the repetition of the second function/pass.

```
def largest_monotonic_subsequence(lst):

    def increasing(lst):
        beg,end,best = 0,0,[0,0]
        for i in range(len(lst)-1):
            if lst[i] <= lst[i+1]:
                end = i+1
                if end - beg > best[1] - best[0]:
                    best = beg, end 
            else:
                beg = i+1
        return (best[0],best[1]+1)

    def decreasing(lst):
        beg,end,best = 0,0,[0,0]
        for i in range(len(lst)-1):
            if lst[i] >= lst[i+1]:
                end = i+1
                if end - beg > best[1] - best[0]:
                    best = beg, end 
            else:
                beg = i+1
        return (best[0],best[1]+1)

    incr = increasing(lst)
    decr = decreasing(lst)
    return lst[slice(*max([incr,decr], key = lambda x: x[1]-x[0]))]
```

Comment: From wikipedia, "*This subsequence is not necessarily contiguous*, or unique"

Comment: [In mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence), a subsequence is a sequence that can be derived from another sequence by deleting some elements without changing the order of the remaining elements. [...] The subsequence should not be confused with substring.

Comment: Oops.  So this question was part of an MIT OCW class I was helping my SO with - after I solved it I googled for "monotonically increasing test" and apparently didn't RTFM closely enough.  If contiguous is not a criteria then I can obviously see why this would be a more difficult problem.  Apologies for the dumb question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sign arg, set to +1 or -1, to reverse the sense of the compare

```
if sgn * lst[i] <= sgn * lst[i+1]:
```